# VS Code extension cursorMove API with multiple selections

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm working on an extension that adds spaces between certain tags, and puts the cursor in the middle. Something like this: `{{ | }}`.

To accomplish this I'm adding two space characters and then moving the cursor back by one character. Currently this works great *unless I use multiple cursors*. Could anyone explain what is happening here given my code below?

[image: Here's what happens when you try with three cursors]

```
class Spacer {
    public space() {
        const editor = window.activeTextEditor;
        let moveBy = {};

        if (! editor) {
            return;
        }

        editor.selections.map(selection => {
            let pos = selection.active;
            let line = editor.document.lineAt(pos.line).text;
            let before = line.slice(Math.max(pos.character - 2, 0), pos.character);
            let after = line.slice(pos.character, pos.character + 2);

            if (before === '{{' && after === '}}') {
                editor.edit(edit => {
                    edit.insert(pos, '  ');
                }, undoOptions);                

                moveBy = { to: 'left', by: 'character' }
            }

            return selection;
        });

        if (Object.keys(moveBy).length > 0) {
            commands.executeCommand('cursorMove', moveBy)
        }
    }

    dispose() {

    }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/46613